# window height calculations stopped when switching to jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, css, height

I have been using jQuery's .height() function to calculate the viewport height and then adjust the css to position divs within the window.

It all worked great until I switched to jQuery 1.9.1 and now it has quit functioning. I tried some back and forths tests between 1.9.1 and 1.8.2 turning other jQuery functions off and on to see if maybe there was some conflict, but everything worked fine in 1.8.2 and everything BUT the window.height code worked fine in 1.9.1

My basic code is below, I am hoping someone can enlighten me as to what I might need to do differently to make this work with 1.9.1 (which I prefer to use due to other functions within the website, this code is used on the homepage only).  The first sets the height for a div with a full background image, the second positions some text on top.

```
   var splashpos = $(window).height() - 121; 
   $('#splash').css({"height": splashpos + "px"});

   var splashttlpos = $(window).height() - 308; 
   $('.splashttl').css({"top": splashttlpos + "px"});
```

Thanks

**Additional bits**

Adding my universal comments back into the question itself.  The doctype is set to html `<!DOCTYPE html>`.  The #splash div is set to position:relative and the .splashttl div is set to position:absolute.  The page is set up body (100% width) -> div#splash (100% width) -> div.wrap (90% width for content) -> div.splashttl (position:absolute to appear in lower right corner).

The jQuery code, first part is to set height of splash to that background image covers the viewport only, scrolling down reveals the overall white background.  The second part is to adjust the top value for position:absolute so that the div sits just above the bottom of the viewport.

And again it works perfectly using jQuery 1.8.2, but does not work with jQuery 1.9.1 (and I have turned off all other scripts to eliminate conflicts to no avail).  I added in the jQuery Migrate script and it works.

So can anyone tell me what has changed about .height() between 1.8.2 and 1.9.1.  And what I need to modify with my code?  I can't find any references in the jQuery documentation.

**Solved (more or less)**

Just on a whim, I decided to try changing the order in which scripts appeared on the webpage. When I moved the code for a content slider below the splash code it started working.  I am not sure why, as when I commented out the content slider script it didn't make any difference, but when I moved it lower it did.

Its a mystery to me, but now everything is working.  Thanks for all the feedback I got.

Comment: Whats your DOCTYPE....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quirks mode, which jQuery doesn't support and removed support for in 1.8.
If your docktype is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Try changing it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Reference [**Quirks_Mode**](http://docs.jquery.com/Won%27t_Fix#Quirks_Mode)

Answer (score 1):

just tested it. it will work if you'll define 'position' for splashttl class.
for example:

```
.splashttl{
   position:relative;
}
```

otherwise jquert will set .splashttl's 'top' proprt to 'auto' for some reason

---edit---

try like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var splashpos = $(window).height() - 121; 
   $('#splash').css({"height": splashpos + "px"});

   $('.splashttl').css({"top": $('#splash').height() - $('.splashttl').height() + 'px', 'left': $(document).width() - $('.splashttl').width() + 'px'});
});
```

again example here: http://freedockstar.com/test.php

and to answer your other question "what has changed about .height() between 1.8.2 and 1.9.1": nothing that i can see. it always returned height of element, and still does...

Comment: All the divs were set to position: relative

Comment: well that would prolly mean, there's something else wrong with your code.
this work just like you would expect it: http://freedockstar.com/test.php

Comment: Actually .splashttl is set position:absolute, as it is appears in the lower right corner.  And the jQuery is supposed to recalculate the top value, so that it appears in the same position irregardless of viewport size.  But as I mentioned earlier everything works perfectly using jQuery1.8.2, and everything but these window.height functions works properly in jQuery1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

See this 
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12388

jQuery doesn't support `quirks` Mode By Any chance you have `quirks` mode enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, there must be something else, here's a demo:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/CcWVX/)

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
   var h = $(window).height();
   var w = $(window).width();
    alert('height: ' + h + ' / width: ' + w);
});
```

You could use document.height instead ([jsfiddle-2](http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/CcWVX/1/)), but it's better to understand what the problem is and fix it.

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
   var h = document.height;
   var w = document.width;
    alert('height: ' + h + ' / width: ' + w);
});
```

Also, you don't need to add "px" to the splashTopPos, if no other value is specified, jQuery defaults to pixels